# CCNY RGB-D tools Installation Problem

Tags: ros, ccny-rgbd, libboost, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I downloaded the tools from github and followed the instructions to install them. However the installation fails with the message

```
Linking CXX executable bin/global_cloud_align
  lib/librgbdtools.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
  lib/librgbdtools.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
  lib/librgbdtools.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
```

Other packages can link to boost normally, so in CMakeLists.txt I added the compile flags for filesystem and system but no luck. I have not messed with the package files in any other way. The rest of the stack's packages also seem to isntall fine.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, I am using ROS Hydro, Boost 1.52 on Ubuntu 12.04
Any suggestions ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191917/ccny-rgb-d-tools-installation-problem/) by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2014-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the late answer,

Your Cmake file isn't able to link Boost to librgbdtools.

Try looking through this link - http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries
to understand exactly how CMake links these libraries (this helped be a lot).

If you know FIND_PACKAGE isn't working, then try setting BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR / LIBRARIES manually, and then linking them. Also, try removing the default PATHS in the FIND_PACKAGE(Boost .....) command.

A hacky solution (not recommended) is to directly specify the libraries themselves in what you link to the rgbdtools.h file.
I'd suggest this as a last resort.

---

Originally posted by [Tanmay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18176/tanmay/) with karma: 110 on 2015-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0